# multiplication function giving a constant random number

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ and I was just learning about functions. My program runs, however, it gives a constant number that doesn't really make any sense to me. Anyway here is my code, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


       int multiplication (int x , int s)
       {
            int v;
            s=x*s;
             return v;
      }

           int main (){
        int u,k,l;
          cout<<"enter two numbers"<<endl;
           cin>>k;
            cin>>l;

          u =    multiplication ( k , l);

          cout <<"the result is "<<u<<endl;

           return 0 ;




        }
```

Comment: Your question should include the input you are giving, and the output you received

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int multiplication (int x , int s)
{
    int v;
    s=x*s;
    return v;
}
```

1. Create a variable `v`. Currently `v` holds an uninitialized (unpredictable) value.
2. Set `s` to the result of the multiplication. Now `s` holds the result of the muliplication, and `v` still holds an unpredictable value.
3. Return the value of `v` (which is unpredictable).

Did you mean to write `return s;`, or maybe `v=x*s;`?

Comment: oh yes actually m i meant to put v instead of s  ! that was a stupid mistake , anyway it all works now , thank you :)